# Stop Cron Job to close reboot infinite loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I had created a script to reboot system after 90% Cpu utilisation. But for some testing purpose i changed the Vlaue of Cpu Utilisation to 0.7%.
And script is programmed to run system reboot.
Because of that Server never online it has got into some infinite reboot loop.

My Script :

```
#!/bin/bash
dstat| awk '{ if (int($1)>0.7) { 
              i=i+1; {
                       print i, $1
               }
              }
           
           if (int($1)>0.7) {
           j=j+1;
           }   
           if (j>2) {
                  print "system reboot";
                  cmd="sudo reboot";
                  system(cmd)
           }
        }'
```

N the script is programmed to run on reboot by using crontab :

```
@reboot /bin/bash /ubuntu/home/reboot.sh
```

So i am unable to login using SSH. Because the system is constant reboot.
My Server is `aws ec2 insatnce`

I have tried passing user data through aws console.

```
sudo apt-get purge dstat
cd /ubuntu/home && sudo rm reboot.sh
sudo /etc/init.d/cron stop
```

But it doesn't work.

So, Any way to get my instance back would be highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- stop the instance
- detach the root volume
- attach it to another instance, already running, in the same availability zone
- mount it at `/mnt`
- fix the misconfiguration by editing the file, which you should find at `/mnt/home/ubuntu/reboot.sh`
- unmount
- detach
- reattach to the original instance
- start the instance